# Select empty Postgis (Postgresql) geometry column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I try to select rows in Postgis that have an empty geometry column.

This works but gives me the opposite:

```
SELECT * FROM foo where geom <> '';
```

And this fails:

```
SELECT * FROM foo where geom = '';

>>>ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
>>>SQL state: XX000
>>>Hint: You must specify a valid OGC WKT geometry type such as POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON
```

And this returns nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM foo where ST_IsEmpty(geom);
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about

```
select * from district.airport  where geom is NULL;
```

Comment: That gives me ERROR: `function isnull(geometry) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: you're right - that will teach me to type sql with out testing - I've updated with working code

Comment: Your update works. Why oh why doesn't it work with an `=` sign but does work with an `is`?

Comment: @RickyA Because NULL values and empty strings are different things. you can check a quick explanation here if you're interested! http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x2632_001.htm

Comment: @nickves Interesting, but still weird that `<> ''` works. Maybe because PG treads empty char as `NULL`. Also this `IS` vs. `=` in sql was the real problem here.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ST_IsEmpty(geom);`

There has to be an empty geometry like `MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY`, otherwise this will return nothing like in your case.

See the documentation for more details at https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsEmpty.html

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
select id, geom, st_isvalid(geom) from foo where st_isvalid(geom)='false' ;
```

You must check that your entities are valid, (if not : repaire geometry).  Then the 'Iant' answer is correct  :

> select * from district.airport  where geom is NULL;

Answer (score 2):

If this works for you, but gives the opposite...

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE geom <> '';
```

Just put a NOT in the statment:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE NOT geom <> ''
```

Comment: Thats a thought....

Answer (score 0):

I have thought about listing tables without geometry which should also be helpful:

```
select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname='yourschemaname'
    except 
    (select f_table_name from geometry_columns where f_table_schema = 'yourschemaname');
```