# What to do if PostGIS gives error that "geometry requires more points"?

Tags: postgis, mapinfo, geometry

I have a .TAB file.

I convert it to ESRI(shp)-->sql and insert it into database.

Using PostGIS when I want to convert the data into ESRI file, it shows an error:

> geometry requires more points

and it didn't generate .prj file...

So how should I handle this problem i.e. what should I do to make the geometry valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you import a shape into PostGIS DB then export the table into a shape. We must have more informations about your problem to solve it:

- How do you import your shape? Your table that contains geometry has a SRID ?

> select distinct(srid(geom)) from my_table;

- What operations do you do in the database? St_transform(geom), st_area(geom), calculate a new field… ?

You can check geometry validity with :

> select distinct(st_isvalid(geom)) from my_table;

-->'t' is valid, 'f' is invalid. Refer to : [Select empty Postgis (Postgresql) geometry column](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65595/select-empty-postgis-postgresql-geometry-column)
-   How do you create your new shape from the DB ?

If FWTools is installed, the following command can be used to create your shape :

> ogr2ogr -f  "Esri Shapefile" name_shape.shp -a_srs "EPSG:4326"
>   PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=database_name user=user_name password=pwd"
>   -sql "select id, name , geom from table_01 where length(id) = 3 "

Comment: i have try what you have suggested using your SQL. when i run the first SQL my SRID = -1 and 2nd SQL, st_isvalid='t'

Comment: ok,you must specify a projection for your table, what is your initial projection shape, (WGS84 maybe?) ??