# Creating difference of two polygon layers using Virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, virtual-layer, st-difference

I am trying to learn the usage of Virtual Layers in QGIS but I can't find a solution for a problem that seems very simple.

I have two polygon layers and I want to have the difference.

Polygon layer 1:
[image: Polygon layer 1]

A "cut" layer:
[image: "cut" layer]

And this is what I want to get:
[image]

How should my query look like to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is to use the [`ST_Union()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) inside of the query (it was also mentioned in
[@geozelot's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418996/creating-difference-of-two-polygon-layers-using-virtual-layer-in-qgis#comment682438_419002)), because features from a "cut" layer need to become one geometry (of type `MULTIPOLYGON`). This idea was taken from this thread : [More on cutting polygons with polygons, in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213851/more-on-cutting-polygons-with-polygons-in-postgis).

Let's assume there are two polygon layers called *'grid_test'* (green) with nine features and *'grid_test2'* (orange) with five features in it, see image below.

[image: input]

So, your query may look like this:

```sql
WITH union_gd2 AS (
    SELECT
        ST_Union(gt2.geometry) as geometry
    FROM
        "grid_test2" AS gt2
    )

SELECT
    gd1.id,
    st_difference(gd1.geometry, ugd2.geometry) AS geometry
FROM
    "grid_test" AS gd1,
    "union_gd2" AS ugd2
WHERE
    st_isvalid(st_difference(gd1.geometry, ugd2.geometry))
```

or like this:

```sql
SELECT
    gd1.id,
    st_difference(gd1.geometry, union_gd2.geometry) AS geometry
FROM
    "grid_test" AS gd1,
    (SELECT
        ST_Union(gt2.geometry) as geometry
    FROM
        "grid_test2" AS gt2
    ) AS union_gd2
WHERE
    st_isvalid(st_difference(gd1.geometry, union_gd2.geometry))
```

and then get the final output

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Select empty Postgis (Postgresql) geometry column](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65595/select-empty-postgis-postgresql-geometry-column)

Answer (score 4):

For a virtual layer, use this query:

```
select st_difference ( p1.geometry, st_intersection ( p1.geometry, p2.geometry )) as geom
from polygon1 as p1, polygon2 as p2
```

*Red outline: Polygon layer 1; blue outline: polygon layer2, orange: output of the virtual layer = red polygons - blue polygons:*
[image]

Comment: This gives not the desired result. It only works correctly with just 1 polygon in the "cut" layer. WIth two polygons as in my example it makes something different.
As far as I understand it, this is because your SQL expression calculates the difference for every possible combination of elements from the two layers.

Comment: You're right, I corrected this, see updated answer

Comment: Your updated solution works in some cases but not in mine. Took me a while to find out why. In my case there exist two polygons in the layer "polygon1" that intersect with both polygons of layer "polygon2" . In this case your solution does not work correctly. I would prefer a foolproof solution that I can easily port to any similar problem in the future.

Comment: Difference is tricky - you want a union of all intersecting 'cut' polygons (`polygon2`) for each 'input' polygon (`polygon1`) to create a complete difference. Note that this is a very costly operation, no matter the software.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Difference" Tool in the Procesing Toolbox. Use the Polygon Layer 1 as Input Layer or "base" and the Polygon Layer 2 as the Overlay Layer or "cutter".

You can leave the rest of the inputs as default (unless you want a physical copy of the layer - you can select an output folder and file type.).

This is the same as ESRI ArcMap's "Erase Tool" and is a reverse clip.

[Link to QGIS Documentation on the Difference Tool](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjq9NXp6ub0AhUeSWwGHZseC8sQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.qgis.org%2F2.6%2Fen%2Fdocs%2Fuser_manual%2Fprocessing_algs%2Fqgis%2Fvector_overlay_tools%2Fdifference.html&usg=AOvVaw1dJDTAVeefDgnnPAO73kJZ)

Comment: Ignore this, did not realise they were both Virtual Layers. @Babel 's answer is better.